# Where can I find charts with the amount of treasuries in existence?

Tags: bonds, united-states

Is there a place where I can see a chart with the amount of treasuries in existence organized by treasury type?

Ideally it would be a resource that has multiple charts (for bills, notes, bonds etc...)

I cannot find anything on the fred.stlouisfed.org site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIFMA: [US Marketable Treasury Issuance, Outstanding, and Interest Rates](https://www.sifma.org/resources/research/us-marketable-treasury-issuance-outstanding-and-interest-rates/)

The hint here is that repurchases are relatively rare and prepayments are not an option so gross issuance that hasn’t yet matured is a decent proxy for outstanding amounts.